# Interrupt a while loop when pressing down a stop button in GUI (python)

Tags: python, user-interface, while-loop, break, wxglade

Currently I am working on a GUI that has two buttons: START and STOP. The idea is that when the user presses down START the code will print everything the user is typing (real time) in a txt file, and once the STOP button is pressed the code will stop printing further typing.
My question is: If I use a loop "while True" in the event when the button start is pressed, immediately the GUI is blocked, and therefore what the event of stop button is blocked (the codes goes into a endless loop)

```
self.close_signal=False

def Start(self,event):

    path=os.chdir(self.pathsave)
    with open(self.tFileName.GetValue()+".txt",'a') as f:

        #This is the cycle I need to break when the button bStop (event Stop)
        while True:
            char=self.getch()
            f.write(char)
            if self.close_signal==True:
                break

def Stop(self,event):
    self.close_signal=True
    f.close()


def getch(self):

    fd = sys.stdin.fileno()
    old_settings = termios.tcgetattr(fd)

    try:
        tty.setraw(sys.stdin.fileno())
        ch = sys.stdin.read(1)
    finally:
        termios.tcsetattr(fd , termios.TCSADRAIN , old_settings)
    return ch
```

This piece of code is included in the class of my wx.Frame
Thanks in advance!

Comment: If you're using a GUI, you almost certainly don't want to also be using console-based IO like `sys.stdin.read` which will probably block the GUI from updating if they work at all. Use your GUI's keyboard events instead! I don't know anything about `wxglade`, so I can't offer a specific solution.

Comment: Ohhh that's a good point. I'd not though about it that way. The thing is that I'm programing a keylogger. So do you have any idea of how can I track the keystrokes when I start the activity when running the GUI?